# JPA, hibernate find() method returns null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb, wildfly, jta

using Hibernate, JPA, Wildfly 11 and EJB, JTA. My Database is Mysql and injecting entityManager with @PersistenceContext.

I am trying to retreive a record from database while it exists in db and its type in my entity is Long while in db is BigInt(20).

```
entityManager.find(peristenceClass.class, 1L)
```

returns null while the same query with :

```
entityManager.createQuery(select a from Entity a where a.id = 1).getResultList()
```

returns the entity.

After retrieving it with createQuery(...) method, find() method returns it too!

this is my entity class definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answersheet")
public class AnswerSheet implements DomainEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "national_code")
    private String nationalCode;

    @Column(name = "mobile")
    private String mobile;

    @Column(name = "client_ip", nullable = false)
    private String clientIp;

    @Column(name = "satisfaction")
    private Integer satisfaction;

    @JoinColumn(name = "questionnaire", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private Questionnaire questionnaire;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNationalCode() {
        return nationalCode;
    }

    public void setNationalCode(String nationalCode) {
        this.nationalCode = nationalCode;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getClientIp() {
        return clientIp;
    }

    public void setClientIp(String clientIp) {
        this.clientIp = clientIp;
    }

    public Integer getSatisfaction() {
        return satisfaction;
    }

    public void setSatisfaction(Integer satisfaction) {
        this.satisfaction = satisfaction;
    }

    public Questionnaire getQuestionnaire() {
        return questionnaire;
    }

    public void setQuestionnaire(Questionnaire questionnaire) {
        this.questionnaire = questionnaire;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof AnswerSheet)) return false;

        AnswerSheet that = (AnswerSheet) o;

        return getId() != null ? getId().equals(that.getId()) : that.getId() == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AnswerSheet{" +
                "id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your entity bean class to the question including all the class annotations and those on your primary key declaration?

Comment: @SteveC: yes dude. I updated the question and added the entity class definition.

Comment: Can you change datatype of id to Integer and try.
And are you sure you atre passing correct entity class in your find method because here I can see difference

Comment: @GarimaGupta: sorry i can not change my id type because it will affect so many codes of project. also about passing correct entity, yes i am passing correct one. the differences here are because of making it brief. I added the entity definition after Steve's comment. I mentioned that the I get correct result with createQuery(...).getResultList() and after calling it, the find() method do it correct too! I guess its a cache problem or something like that from hibernate.

Comment: I think we need to see all the code around that initial `find` call. This is a fundamental JPA operation and I  would be really surprised if it did not work, otherwise there would be a lot more screaming happening.

Comment: @HamidAdldoost: For entityManager.find(peristenceClass.class, 1L) to work, the class/entity should be the managed entity of that entity manager. So, unless you show the code that you are using to perform find() and createquery() it is not possible to answer whats going wrong.

Comment: Are any of the fields marked as `nullable = false` null by any chance? I've had a similar issue in the past and that was the cause.